# altium TI webbench, populate footprint in schematic

Tags: altium, texas-instruments

I have exported a design from Ti webbench in Altium format. I have used "project-component links" to link up the schematic and PCB.

The PCB has footprints set but the schematic does not which causes problems when generating the BoM. Using "update schematics" doesn't seem to push the footprints to the schematic. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "update schematics" will change the footprint in the schematic if it is set to something, but won't set it if it is not set at all which seems to be the case with altium schematics exported from webbench.

The workaround is to select the components on the schematic and then use the inspector to set the footprint to an arbitary value. After doing this you can use "update schematics" to update the footprints in the schematic to the correct values from the PCB.

Comment: Imports to Altium can be weird. I have imported a lot from PCAD into Altium and had the same problems. I ended up fixing everything by syncing all the schematics and pcb to a single library. This makes any changes to the design much easier moving forward.